# Gephi crashes while loading the sample file

Tags: java, openjdk, jre

I was trying to install gephi for some network analysis. Initially there was problem with the Java Runtime Environment that is installed. I removed the Open JRE and installed the Oracle JRE 8u77. Even that gave some problems and when I looked online I figured that there is some trouble using JRE version 8 with gephi so I un-installed Java completely from the system and then installed JRE version 7. I was able to run in after that by typing ./gephi but when I load the Power-Grid sample file it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer and wanted to share with you guys. In the gephi website it is mentioned that in order to run the software we are supposed to type ./gephi in the command line. Instead try LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 ./gephi 
This fixes any issues which occur while running the gephi software.